# How can I flag a harmful anonymous suggested edit?

Tags: support, editing, flagging, suggested-edits

I'm new to the "Suggested Edits" review queue. Recently, I was asked to review an edit suggested by an anonymous user which if accepted would actively harm our site. I rejected the edit. Is there a way to flag an edit by an anonymous user in order to prevent such circumstances in future?

I didn't include that edit in my question as I think it's a really (really) bad edit which affects the sanity of our community.

I think I'm not the first person to receive such a terrible edit:
[Why do we allow anonymous users to suggest edits?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7010/238167)

Comment: I agree the edit is bad, but if you think it's "really really bad" then maybe you haven't seen the bottom of that particular barrel yet. (It is easy enough to identify from your user profile, Activity > All Actions > Reviews, and then on the question timeline. Not that you should have posted the link, just keep in mind that it's reasonably public already.)

Comment: FWIW, I think I reject almost all suggested edits by anonymous users. There are some that are useful, but most I find are spam or vandalism or completely useless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Raise a custom moderator flag on the edited post, and we'll look at it. It's possible for the diamond moderators to remove a user's editing privileges, but we almost never need to do that.

For anonymous edits that introduce spam or vandalize the post, reject them as spam or vandalism. If enough of those rejections accumulate, [the IP address associated with the edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118213/is-there-some-form-of-blocking-in-place-for-rejected-suggested-edits-by-anonymou) will become hobbled and unable to anonymously suggest edits.